# Img tag not displayed on the browser when client requests acess to it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Evening, beginner here.

I wanted to make a local static website that just displays an image on a head tag of an html file, the node in charge of sending the response to the client seems to work fine, but the issue is that the client never gets the image displayed on the browser and instead, gets the text content in the alt property.

This is the js file that handles requests and sends responses:

```
const {createServer} = require("http");
const {readFile} = require("fs").promises;
let server = createServer((request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  readFile("./home.html").then(file => response.end(file.toString()));
});
server.listen(8000);
console.log("Listening! (port 8000)");
```

And this is the html sent as a response:

```
<html>
    <head><img src="img/testimg.jpg" alt="Test image" /></head>
</html>
```

I don't know if the issue is on the server or on the html file, because the server sends the file but only the alt property is displayed when i go to http://localhost:8000/ in the browser, i belive it might be a problem with the way i linked the image file, because when i link an image from the internet it display that image well, i tried changing it to "./img/testimg.jpg" but it doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: have you looked at express.js ? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Comment: @Tareq don't know about that, im using mainly vanilla nodejs due to an exersive im trying to make from this book: https://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html#i_TLRTlwK6ZU and even thought the book doesn't ask me to make a local website with images, i'd like to know how can i make one with them.

Answer (score 1):

You are always sending the `home.html` file.

When you open the page your browser try to open http://localhost:8000/img/testimg.jpg but this just call the function inside `createServer` again and you end up sending the `home.html`.

You can try to put some logic in the function to distinguish the two url or use a more complete solution (take a look to `express.js`) instead.

P.S. "Non meta tags" should go under `<body>` tag, not `<head>`